# Changing value of label with combobox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, combobox, label

This is probably a really basic question, but I'm been out of programming for a few years so here it goes. I'm trying to make a combobox with certain values and when I press one of the values, I want labels to change their values.

Lets say I have a value "TEST" in the combobox, when selected, I want the label lblHeight to be changed to "TEST". I code I've tried is below, but I can't understand why it doesn't work. Can someone help?

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "TEST")
        {
            lblHeight.Text = "TEST";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Quote from MSDN docs on property `ComboBox.SelectedText`: "If `DropDownStyle` is set to `DropDownList`, the return value is an empty string ("")." Try reading `SelectedItem` and converting it to string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `SelctedItem` instead of `SelectedText`, like this:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "TEST")
    {
        lblHeight.Text = "TEST";
    }
}
```